blazor server upload file stream to api cdn
In Blazor.Server you need to upload files over 400 MB to CDN.
Code that works fine with InteractiveWebAssembly
private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
const long CHUNKSIZE = 1024 * 400; // subjective

var file = e.File;
long uploadedBytes = 0;
long totalBytes = file.Size;
long percent = 0;
int fragment = 0;
long chunkSize;

using (var inStream = file.OpenReadStream(long.MaxValue))
{
    blockView = false;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Url))
    {
        model.Url = null;
    }
    _uploading = true;
    var contentType = Path.GetExtension(file.Name);            
    while (_uploading)
    {
        chunkSize = CHUNKSIZE;
        if (uploadedBytes + CHUNKSIZE > totalBytes)
        {// remainder
            chunkSize = totalBytes - uploadedBytes;
        }

        var chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
        await inStream.ReadAsync(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
        // upload this fragment

        var fileContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(chunk));

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"https://{cdn_url}/{model.Files.Name}/{(fragment++).ToString("D8")}");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", model.Files.Token);
        request.Content = fileContent;
        // put
        var response = await Http.SendAsync(request);


        // Update our progress data and UI
        uploadedBytes += chunkSize;
        percent = uploadedBytes * 100 / totalBytes;
        echo = $"Dowloand {percent}%  {(uploadedBytes / 1e+6).ToString("F2")} mb in {(totalBytes / 1e+6).ToString("F2")} mb";
        if (percent >= 100)
        {// upload complete
            _uploading = false;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(fragment +" " + fileContent.Headers.ContentLength);
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    var requestItog = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"https://{cdn_url}/{model.Files.Name + contentType}");
    requestItog.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", model.Files.Token);
    requestItog.Headers.Add("X-Object-Manifest", $"{Container_Name}/{model.Files.Name}/");
    // put
    var responseItog = await Http.SendAsync(requestItog);

    model.Url = model.Files.Name + contentType;
    AddName.InvokeAsync(model.Files.Name + contentType);
}

}

added to the program.cs
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddHubOptions(o => o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 100000000);

checking the 1.37 MB image showed that they arrived intact in size but broken.

How to avoid broken bytes.
Tried to reduce the size of CHUNKSIZE to 32 kb, despite the longer loading the file is still broken. Although much smaller.

Try to add controller in your blazor sever app, then use webapi to upload resources, the problem should be solved. The root cause is that signalr is used for communication in blazor server app.

I need to send to the provider's server via API, why do I need my controller?

What I mean is, by adding a custom webapi controller, we can isolate the problem and verify whether this problem is limited by signalr.

you can try, but the pictures load completely normally after adding the message size Program.cs

The logic around chunkSize is complicated and possibly incorrrect.  ReadAsync returns the actual number of bytes read. Use 1 buffer (byte[]) and upload what you received, not what you asked for. Receiving 0 bytes signals EOF.
